# Cross-platform application and website tools

Tags: programming-languages, cross-platform, web-frameworks

I am software engineering student, and we have assignment to create a system, which should be cross-platform, and should be implemented as a desktop app, and moreover, same interface and capabilities should be ported to internet(though I can choose the we server's OS).
I have decent skills in python/django and ruby/rails, but python/ruby are pretty nasty on windows... Could someone please recommend some tools which I could use,
Thanks in advance

Comment: At least Python works just fine on Windows.

Comment: Given your requirements, I'd think that the best matches for implementation platform are Java, Flash/Flex, and Silverlight (Mono on non-Windows platforms)

Comment: @delnan python is pain in the *** on windows. It needs interpreter to be installed, it makes your program open source, zc.buildout doesn't(?) natively work on windows. All in all python is just not the way to write windows programs

Comment: cx_Freeze (http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) works fine for me, even for Python 3. Creates an executable that runs without interpreter. It also makes it harder to get the source (I don't know how easy this is, but if you distribute only the bytecode, Python is equal to e.g. Java in this regard), if that concerns you.

Comment: @delnan well thanks for pointing me to cx_Freeze :). I only knew py2exe, which hasn't been updated for a long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is not bad:

- Using [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) you can create AJAX application easily and re-use code between the browser and  the server
- Swing and [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) are nice libraries for creating desktop/Windows application
- Your webserver can run on Windows or UNIX/Linux
- Many libraries and web frameworks and persistence frameworks available

I wrote about this on my blog once too:
http://www.databasesandlife.com/java-really-delivers-write-once-run-anywhere/

Comment: I would have chosen Java at first place, but I am not familiar with any Java web frameworks, maybe you could suggest any?

Comment: I have had good experiences with Wicket. GWT is also good but addresses a slightly area, it (in short) creates Javascript to run in the browser. But there are no doubt many others, which have their advantages as well. I have heard good things about JSF.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is JAVA. it's truely cross platform, you can run your package on windows, linux, Mac OS and it can be run from a website (or in a browser)

Comment: Quite a few languages are truly cross-platform. This might have been Java's unique perk back in the 90s... but now, most (popular) languages that compile to bytecode have insanely portable implementations.

Comment: true, that's why i didn't say it was the ONLYone, just that it is truely cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to use java as a language to develop cross platform application as well as for interenet.

Answer (score 0):

What I feel for your requirement

1. Your view/presentation tier  should be separated, which run on cross platform like Flash or QT.
2. Business logic you will on server. You can use ruby to implement the same.

You can use ruby with both the technologies. Ruby with flex(Flash) or ruby with QT.